# Incorrect reference to a line in algorithmic using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, algorithms, algorithmicx

I am using `algpseudocode` and `algorithm` packages to typeset pseudocode. I also use `float`, `hyperref` and `caption` packages. The problem is that when I reference a line in the pseudocode, the number is correct, but when I click it, the document moves to the beginning of the chapter and not the algorithm.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Heading}
Reference to the line \ref{line}.
\Blindtext
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Statement \label{line}
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Example}
\label{alg}
\end{algorithm}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to do this.  As said, just loading a new version of `cleveref` partially fixes the problem, links are now to line numbers rather than the start of the chapter; but when there are two or more algorithms `hyperref`'s link doesn't distinguish the same line number in different algorithms.  The simplest solution is just to load `hyperref` via

```
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
```

This changes all link names in to something unique, but not humanly recognisable/meaningful.  If you think this is a blunderbust approach, then you can just define `\theHALG@line` appropriately, to give unique links, via

```
\providecommand\theHALG@line{\thealgorithm.\arabic{ALG@line}}
```

In `hyperref` each `\thecounter` has a corresponding `\theHcounter` which can be redefined the create unique identifiers.  In your case, `algorithm` provides a unique container for your `algorithmic` environment, and so its number representation can be used to distinguish different instances.

Because of the `@` symbols in the command names above, you will have to put this code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\theHALG@line{\thealgorithm.\arabic{ALG@line}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Heading}

Here's the first test to line \ref{test1} of Algorithm \ref{alg1}.\\
Here's the second test to line \ref{test2} of Algorithm \ref{alg1}.
Here's the first test to line \ref{test21} of Algorithm \ref{alg2}.\\
Here's the second test to line \ref{test22} of Algorithm \ref{alg2}.

\begin{algorithm}[p]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement    
    \State Statement    \label{test1}
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement    \label{test2}
    \State Statement
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Example}
\label{alg1}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[p]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement    
    \State Statement    \label{test21}
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement    \label{test22}
    \State Statement
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Example}
\label{alg2}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your second solution doesn't work when the `acmart` document class is in use, as it seems it provides its own version of `\theHALG@line` (which doesn't work right). Using `\renewcommand` instead of `\providecommand` seems to do the job, though.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) did not take [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) into consideration, at least not fully...

The macro `\ALG@step` is in charge of writing out the line numbers (taken from [`algorithmicx.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.sty)):

```
\def\ALG@step%
   {%
   \addtocounter{ALG@line}{1}%
   \addtocounter{ALG@rem}{1}%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALG@rem}}{\ALG@numberfreq}}%
      {\setcounter{ALG@rem}{0}\alglinenumber{\arabic{ALG@line}}}%
      {}%
   }%
```

Note how the line numbers are stepped using `\addtocounter{ALG@line}{1}`. This doesn't set a hyper-target - an anchor to which a link can jump. Inside, it should use `\refstepcounter{ALG@line}`. If you use/add to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\def\ALG@step%
   {%
   \refstepcounter{ALG@line}% Step and anchor for hyperref
   \stepcounter{ALG@rem}% Regular step (equivalent to \addtocounter{ALG@rem}{1})
   \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALG@rem}}{\ALG@numberfreq}}%
      {\setcounter{ALG@rem}{0}\alglinenumber{\arabic{ALG@line}}}%
      {}%
   }%
\makeatother
```

your hyperlinks should work fine.

---

It should be mentioned that the optional argument of the `algorithmic` environment is meant to show line numbers with steps. For example, it allows one to only show every second line number. It may seem odd then to jump to (say) line 2 when there is no line 2 visibly marked in the algorithm. The above adjustment allows one to do just that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Heading}
Reference to the line 1 of Alg. \hyperlink{line}{\ref{alg1}}.
Reference to the line 8 of Alg. \hyperlink{line8}{\ref{alg1}}.
\Blindtext
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]\hypertarget{line}{}
    \State Statement 
    \State Statement 
    \State Statement 
    \State Statement 
    \State Statement 
    \State Statement 
    \State Statement \hypertarget{line8}{}
    \State Statement 
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Example}\label{alg1}
\label{alg}
\end{algorithm}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Actually, a `\phantomsection` helps in jumping to the beginning of the algorithm, but not the specified line. Try adding a few more `\State`s, and add a `\label` to the last one. You will see that a `\ref` will print the correct line number, but clicking it does not jump to the right one. (Though we can add a `\phantomsection` to each referenced line.)

Comment: ok, see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, your edited answer did not quite work for me: First, it does not print the line number automatically, and second, it does not link to it (rather, it links to the algorithm itself). However, I took your excellent idea of using `\phantomsection`s, and turned it into a working solution. Please check [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156020/1347).

Answer (score 1):

I took an idea, originally conceived by @Herbert, and used it in my answer. The idea is to use `\phantomsection` before each `\label` which refers to some line of the algorithm. As this repeated pattern calls for defining a new macro, I defined `\plabel` as follows:

```
\newcommand\plabel[1]{\phantomsection\label{#1}}
```

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}

\newcommand\plabel[1]{\phantomsection\label{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Heading}

Here's the first test to line \ref{test1} of Algorithm \ref{alg}.\\
Here's the second test to line \ref{test2} of Algorithm \ref{alg}.

\begin{algorithm}[p]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement    
    \State Statement    \plabel{test1}
    \State Statement
    \State Statement
    \State Statement    \plabel{test2}
    \State Statement
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Example}\label{alg1}
\label{alg}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```