# Reference to substeps (substates) of an algorithm

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, subequations, algorithmic

I'm using the algorithmicx package, and also a substate (substep) environment from the answer [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352033/sub-numbering-in-an-algorithm). The problem is that referring to the substates, and even some normal states is broken.

I tried tweaking the algsubstates macro, but I don't know how to modify it so that the substates a, b, c are considered separately per algorithm and per line; currently it seems to me that it's global for the whole document, and that's why it's reset every time (`\setcounter` line).

```
\newcounter{algsubstate}
\renewcommand{\thealgsubstate}{\alph{algsubstate}}
\newenvironment{algsubstates}
  {\setcounter{algsubstate}{0}%
   \renewcommand{\State}{%
     \stepcounter{algsubstate}%
     \Statex {\footnotesize\thealgsubstate:}\space}}
  {}
```

Here's a MWE in a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/qjp4TmpR), for some reason in my actual document the reference *words* are not broken, only the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the original `\ref` does not point to the right lines either. The problem was with hyperref the whole time, see this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156404/105199) here.

The workaround is simply the following:

```
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
```